# differentiability on $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a real valued function as below:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x \text{ belongs to Cantor set } \\ 0 &\text{otherwise }. \end{cases}$

I know that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on every $ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C$ but what can we say about  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being differentiable on points like  $ x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C$ ?

Comment: The derivative, if it exists on $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$, is clearly $0$.  What is your definition of being differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ using the same argument why it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$.

By construction of $C$, you know that for each point $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus C$. On this neighbourhood is $f$ constant $0$ which yields that your function is continuous and differentiable on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$C$ is closed therefore $\mathbb R \setminus C$ is open. Let $x \in \mathbb R \setminus C$. Then there exists an open set $U$ such that $U \subseteq \mathbb R \setminus C$. Now, $f \equiv 0$ on U. Hence $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: $f \equiv 1$ on $C$ but it's not even continuous on $C$

Comment: @ArshGh what is your definition of a continuous function?

Comment: @ArshGh It is not continuous on $\mathbb R$. Constant functions are are not only continuous but also differentiable on their domain.

Comment: I'm considering $f$ as a function on whole $\mathbb R$ but I wanna know that if $f$ is differentiable on points of $\mathbb R \setminus C$ @SahibaArora

Comment: @ArshGh It is. Since if you restrict the domain to $\mathbb R \setminus C$, it is a constant function. Continuity and differentiability are local properties. So it doesn't matter what it is defined outside.

Comment: I explained my question poorly , I didn't restrict the domain... @SahibaArora

Comment: @ArshGh I edited my answer.

Comment: @SahibaArora thanks

Answer (score 2):

For each point in the complement of the Cantor set, there exists a two-sided neighborhood of that point contained in the complement of the Cantor set (because the complement of the Cantor set is an open subset of the reals), and hence the function is zero in a two-sided neighborhood of that point, and hence the derivative at that point exists and equals zero. So $f'(x)=0$ for each $x \in C.$